# save output of neural network in keras and tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have created a siamese neural network to measure the similarity of images in a dataset, the problem I have is that the process of comparing two images is time-consuming due to the depth of the network. I have noticed that in these cases, they save the output of the network for each image so that the features of each image are available and at the time of comparison, they compare the set of features, which have much smaller dimensions than the original image. How can I save network output?

```
def build_siamese_model(inputShape, embeddingDim=70):
  model_resnet = tensorflow.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False,
           weights='imagenet',
           pooling='avg',
           input_shape=IMG_SHAPE
           )
  for layer in model_resnet.layers[0:-25]:
    layer.trainable = False
  model = Dense(embeddingDim)(model_resnet.output)
  model =Model(inputs=model_resnet.input, outputs=model)
  model.summary()
  return model


def euclidean_distance(vectors):
    # unpack the vectors into separate lists
    (featsA, featsB) = vectors
    # compute the sum of squared distances between the vectors
    sumSquared = K.sum(K.square(featsA - featsB), axis=1,
        keepdims=True)
    # return the euclidean distance between the vectors
    return K.sqrt(K.maximum(sumSquared, K.epsilon()))

imgA = Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE)
imgB = Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE)
featureExtractor = build_siamese_model(IMG_SHAPE)
featsA = featureExtractor(imgA)
featsB = featureExtractor(imgB)
distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance)([featsA, featsB])
outputs = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(distance)
model = Model(inputs=[imgA, imgB], outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam",
    metrics=["accuracy"])
```

i want something to get all images features once and after that instead compare images with another images just compare features

Comment: ```model(images)``` ?...